# document.documentElement.innerHTML not updated on page change

Tags: javascript, firefox, innerhtml

In firefox, when I load a page and from the console I read `"document.documentElement.innerHTML"` all works fine. If I click on a different link and I again read `"document.documentElement.innerHTML"`, the result is the same as for the previous page.

Doing a ctrl+u (view-source) instead shows the right source code. Any idea on why this might happen?
(I am testing this specifically on Facebook)

Comment: You should add your code to question

Comment: I open the console (F12) and inside I type copy(document.documentElement.innerHTML) and paste it in notepad. That's it. No code is involved.

Comment: FYI, I'm seeing this same behavior, also with Facebook. Any insight would be super helpful!